# derivative power rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm looking at a programming text that says the following:

> The rule for differentiating powers says that the derivative of
>   $[u(x)]^n$ with respect to $x$ is equal to $n[u(x)]^{n-1}$ times the
>   derivative of $u(x)$ with respect to $x$.

So $\frac{d}{dx}[u(x)]^n$

is

$n[u(x)]^{n-1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}u(x)$

I'm not understanding the mathematical formalities here of that additional $\frac{d}{dx}u(x)$ expression. What does it mean? Is there anything else to do with it?

Comment: The last expression says you should derive that function

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} u(x)= u'(x)$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ where $f(x) = x^2$, so $\frac{d}{dx}x^2$. This should just be $2x$, not $2x \cdot \frac{d}{dx}x^2$. This is circular.

Comment: The rule you ask about follows immediately from the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). Is that what you're asking...? (I'm afraid there are too many pronouns for me in "What does it mean? Is there anything else to do with it?")

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are confused at has to do with what variable you are doing derivative (correct me if I'm wrong).

in looking at 
 $\frac{d}{dx} ([u(x)]^n)$

It would be helpful to mention that

$\frac{d}{du} ([u(x)]^n) = n\cdot [u(x)]^{n-1} $

notice the difference of this equation to the top. One is doing derivative w.r.t. x, one is doing derivative w.r.t. the function u.

Now applying the chain rule,  if you are doing derivative of x inside a composite function  $[u(x)]^n$ , it would be the same as derivative of  $[u(x)]^n$ w.r.t. u multiplying by derivative of $u(x)$ itself

$\frac{d}{dx} ([u(x)]^n) = n\cdot [u(x)]^{n-1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx} (u(x)) $

for example, say $u(x) = sin(x)$

then $\frac{d}{dx} ([sin(x)]^n) = n\cdot [sin(x)]^{n-1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx} (sin(x)) $

$\hspace{35 mm} $$ = n\cdot [sin(x)]^{n-1}\cdot cos(x)$